# How can I make the last element of this CSS DYNAMIC Columns grid to occupy all the columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well, I have this box container class which is a CSS Grid container. As you can see, it's dynamic because of using `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr))`

```css
.box-container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Resizing the viewport's width, we can get to this situation:
[image]

I want that last element to occupy two columns instead of just one, but I can't manage to set that dynamically.

So this is what I expect once I get to that point resizing the viewport's width:

[image]

But I only know how to do that statically, spanning that last child. And it's not what I want because I only want it to span the two columns in that point of the viewport's width, and setting it up not dynamically would make it to span ALWAYS the two columns.

Comment: You can try `flex`. `flex-grow` properties.

Comment: Or you could use something like `:nth-child(3n):last-child { grid-column: 1 / 2; }`

Comment: I can do that, but that's not dynamic. It'd make the last box to take the two columns forever, when I just want it to take the two columns ONLY when there are two rows or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the required behaviour easily by using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). The [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) propery will take care of adjusting the items inside the container.

So, when you have small screen device, `flex-wrap` will move the items those overflows to a new `row`. Hence, we use [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) to tell the items to grow based on the space available.

And the [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) will tell the items to limit the minimun `width` it can shrink.

Here is the working example.

```css
.box-container {
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 150px;

}
.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jamesweb/pen/ZEEWxee) which demostrated above example.